# Wrong fileending in internetexplorer (Zip instead of DGIX)

Tags: internet-explorer, download

In Internetexplorer we implemented a preview for documents, pictures and so on. The file will be directly shown in internet explorer or download it, when you can't show it in Browser.

Usualy this works fine, but for the fileendig DGIX we have a strange behavior in Internet Explorer (11) (Chrome and Firefox works how expected)

The file will be downloaded as ZIP.

[image]

This is the response header.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 12176
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=P000022987.DGIX
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 21 Dec 2018 10:12:19 GMT
```

Do someone knows why IE behaves like this?

Comment: If i download it with "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=P000022987.DGIX" in header IE behaves like it should. But I can not change to attachment because we want usualy show the document inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be a client side registry mismatch issue, for the handling of these file-types, between the Windows Shell Explorer and Internet Explorer.

You can try to turn off Internet Explorer handling for these MIME types, so that it defaults to the Shell handler. 
For that you need to change the **iexplorer.exe DWORD value**, from ‘**1**’ to ‘**0**’, in the following Registry key:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_MIME_HANDLING

**You can do the same by applying Group policy.**

(1) Type **gpedit.msc** in Run window to open Local group policy editor.

(2) Navigate to location below.

> Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Security Features\Consistent MIME Handling

(3) Find the key named as **Internet Explorer Processes**.

(4) Double click on it to configure this setting.

(5) User can click on **Disabled** option to disable this policy.

(6) Click on **Apply** button to apply this change and click **OK** to close the configuration window.

Comment: if i change this it works fine. But i can not change all the clients. Do you have any idea how i can reach this from server side?

Comment: @Thomas, You can try to apply group policy from server side. I modified my previous answer. you can refer it to get the steps for the group policy.